# MARS emulator for MIPS Error: address out of range 0x20000000

Tags: mips

I am not sure where I am messing up, but I am using the MARS emulator for MIPS and am running into an error at my

`lw $s6, 0($s7) #s6 now holds c[i]` line.

here is my error:

```
Error in C:\Programming\mips1.asm line 14: Runtime exception at 0x00400020: address out of range 0x20000000

Go: execution terminated with errors.
```

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    add $s0, $zero, $zero
    lui $s3, 0x2000
        addi $s5, $zero, 100
        addi $sp, $sp, -8
Loop:
    slt $t2, $s0, $s5
    beq $zero, $t2, Exit
    sll $s7, $s0, 2
    add $s7, $s7, $s3 #s7 is now the address of c[i]
    lw $s6, 0($s7) #s6 now holds c[i]
    slt $t3, $s0, $s1 #set t3 if i is less than a
    bne $zero, $t3, Else
    sw $s2, 0($s7) #stores b into c[i] 
    add $s0, $s0, 1
    j Loop
Else:   add $s2, $zero, $s6
    add $s0, $s0, 1
    j Loop
Exit:   addi $sp, $sp, 8

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, turns out I needed an address that was lower in order for it to be a part of the heap. MARS heap starts at 0x10040000 and moves up.

I changed 0x2000 to 0x1005 and it worked in MARS